# How do decentralised systems deal with all nodes being killed

Tags: design, distributed-computing

In relation to DHT's (distributed hash tables), how do decentralised systems deal with all nodes disconnecting and thus having its routing meta data invalidated? i.e with the implementation of DHT's in torrent clients, what would happen if all nodes (including the root/parent) were to become inactive? Would it mean all subsequent nodes that join wouldn't be able to see anyone thus invalidating the system?

If this is the case, then is it wise to only use decentralisation on a system that will have constant connections? Or is it the case that its recommended to have the root/parent node be a centralised sever with the dedicated task of keeping the system alive, to create a hybrid mix of centralised & decentralisation?

Comment: Presumably, if even one node comes back up again, it will still have its routing data stored somewhere.  It's very difficult to completely eliminate every trace of data everywhere in a distributed system; that sort of data resiliency is kind of the whole point.

Comment: I gather this is from the perspective that the table has lots of nodes, I'm more concerned with resilience with a low node count, i.e 2-3 nodes. In that instance, is it not quite probable that all nodes will be offline at some point and could all be assigned a new IP? I'm coming to the conclusion that resilience is only in large numbers?

Comment: Why would you need a large number of nodes for resiliency?  Three nodes is already triply-redundant.

Comment: https://jameshfisher.com/2017/08/11/peer-to-peer-discovery/

Comment: For the same point the article you linked states: "Have the new process send a “ping” packet to every address on the internet, until one replies with a “pong”.". Now lets take a common scenario, 3 nodes, all living in the UK. Its 11PM and all 3 nodes disconnect to get some sleep. The next morning node 1 & 2 comes back online but with new IP addresses because their ISP have reassigned them new ones. Now the whole table is invalid because no one knows where to find each other? Am I misunderstanding something because it seems like you always need one active connection to stay valid.

Comment: In the case of BitCoin and their DNS trick, that's a centralised approach because you rely on dedicated systems to realign the routing table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94126/discussion-between-kieran-devlin-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 1):

What happens when a new node comes online while all existing nodes are offline depends on the strategy that the designers of the p2p network have designed for setting up the initial network and discovery of that network by new nodes.

For a completely new node, there are several possibilities

- If the discovery strategy is to ping (a subsection of) the internet, then failing to find an existing network would probably result in the creation of a new network that is disconnected from the original one.
- As described [here](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/08/11/peer-to-peer-discovery/), the blind ping strategy can be very time consuming, so many p2p clients come with a list of "initial peers", where the expectation is that at least some of those machines will be reachable. When none are reachable, the client will likely give an error and fail to start. 
  The larger the list of "initial peers" is, the easier it becomes for the maintainers of those machines to coordinate that at least some are online, even if the connections are not that reliable.

For a node that used to be connected and comes back after a service interruption, it would first try to reconnect to the peers that it was previously connected to. If none of those are reachable, then the software could give an error and/or allow the user to restart as-if it is a new node joining the network.

Using a list of "initial peers", even if that list contains only one entry, does not make the network less decentralized, as long as the existing nodes can reconnect to each other while all "initial peers" are unreachable.

To reduce the risk of an "initial peer" not being reachable due to IP address reassignments, those addresses can be published as domain addresses, because domain names are not as easily reassigned as IP addresses and the DNS registry can be updated dynamically.

Another way to increase the availability of "initial peers" is to let servers (for example the project's webserver) also join the network. In contrast to home computers, servers tend to have stable IP addresses and don't go offline for the night.

Comment: Another strategy is to use a centralized abstracted append-only queue. New nodes receive updates about other nodes in the  system from the queue, and thus build an initial list by replaying the queue. Hosting the queue itself requires some form of uninterrupted downtime and a stable DNS name, so this would be a subset of your answer - thought it was worth adding.